# Find Text in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<div data-ng-if="!newRequestReceived" class="ng-scope">
                <!-- ngIf: !authRequestCount --><p data-ng-if="!authRequestCount" class="ng-scope" style="" xpath="1">No more candidates awaiting Authorization</p><!-- end ngIf: !authRequestCount -->
                <!-- ngIf: authRequestCount -->
            </div>
```

I need help,

if find string like "`No more candidates awaiting Authorization`"

the loop will working How???

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='ng-scope'][contains('No more candidates awaiting Authorization']"));
```

this is correct

Comment: 'the loop will working How???; what you mean in this line?

Comment: There is no loop.. do you mean to use `driver.findElements` (not the s for plural)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the string **No more candidates awaiting Authorization** you don't need a loop as such. As the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  String myString = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.ng-scope[data-ng-if*='newRequestReceived'] p.ng-scope[data-ng-if*='authRequestCount']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  String myString = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'newRequestReceived')]//p[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'authRequestCount')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Comment: Thank you So much, and i want testing in already opened Firefox Tab. help me

Comment: actually i need find candidates waiting for authorization, in Mettl Online Portal,  actually we (100 peoples ) tried mouse click for back and authorize button, i want easy to handle this action in selenium automation, so that i trying .... in my program: Open Firefox ->Login Page ->Insert User & Pwd and login ->Click All Test - > Click Authorize Button, in my problem is when find text "No more candidates awaiting Authorization" after clicking authorize button, GoTo All Test -> Click Authorize, if find candidate, it will stop, once check and approve, then goTo same thing Alltest - >authorize

Comment: @YaserArafath I have answered the question as per the best possible way I understood it. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @YaserArafath Contributors of StackOverflow won't have access to _Mettl Online Portal_. So when you would raise the question you have to provide the relevant _HTML_ for us to refer to help us constructing an Answer for you.

Comment: while (true){
WebElement myString = null;
String tt = "No more candidates";
try {
String myString = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'newRequestReceived')]//p[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'authRequestCount')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
break;
}
if (myString == tt)
{
System.out.println(myString);
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("All Test")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Authorize")).click();

}
}

Comment: hi @debanjanB this is my conditional code, can you please check  NOTE: some text / Xpath  are shortened due to limit of characters

Comment: Note: i am not developer / Test Engineer am a Creative Designer.  Sorry for my poor English,

Comment: @YaserArafath Please gather all your requirements, your code trials and the error you are seeing and raise a **new question**. Definitely StackOverflow contributors will help you out.